# Celery workers take 5 jobs immediately despite telling them not to

Tags: python, celery

I start my celery workers with

```
celery -A workerTasks worker --concurrency 1
```

In django's settings.py I also have:

```
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

But the workers still consume 5 tasks as soon as they connect to the celery broker.

What am I missing?

Comment: what version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Ok,so my mistake was that I was setting the config on the server-side rather than the worker-side.  When creating the Celery app I can set the configuration explicitly like this:

```
app = Celery('workerTasks', broker='whatever')


app.conf['worker_prefetch_multiplier'] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still want use Django's settings.py for celery, you should replace **CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER** with **CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER**

```
CELERY_WORKER_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
```

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#django-support

> For Django users and others who want to keep uppercase names
>
> If you’re loading Celery configuration from the Django settings module then you’ll want to keep using the uppercase names.
>
> You also want to use a CELERY_ prefix so that no Celery settings collide with Django settings used by other apps.
> To do this, you’ll first need to convert your settings file to use the new consistent naming scheme, and add the prefix to all Celery related settings:

```
 $ celery upgrade settings proj/settings.py --django
```

> After upgrading the settings file, you need to set the prefix explicitly in your proj/celery.py module:

```
 app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you use Celery 4.x now and it does not pick the `worker_prefetch_multiplier` setting because you use the uppercase one? Celery, since 4.0, uses the all lower-case configuration values (this is well-documented).

You can easily check this by running: `celery -A workerTasks inspect conf`.

If your concurrency level is 1, and `worker_prefetch_multiplier` is 1, and if you run 5 workers, they will immediately run 5 tasks, and prefetch an extra 5...